# Detect Mac OS going to sleep from java to prevent sqlite database corruption

Tags: java, macos, sqlite

I'm writing a Java application that processes a large dataset - transforming it into an sqlite3 database around 100 - 150Gb in size. This takes a while, and so I need my laptop (Macbook Air) to run for a few days.

As a student, I also need to use my laptop out and about so I can't guarantee I'll always have access to power. At around a quarter of the way through OSX went to sleep, and then crashed when trying to wake up, corrupting a precious 30Gb of data.

What I would like to do is detect that the OS is going to sleep from java and then terminate the program safely. Is this possible or is there a better solution (aside from the obvious - don't run the app while on battery power)? The only information I've found online is using objective c with I/O kit.

Comment: Why don't you turn off automatic sleep in your Macbook?

Comment: Just use transaction of the appropriate size.

Comment: @saifahmad because I can't guarantee having enough battery to continue execution between charges - I need to be able to sleep if need be then resume when I connect back to the power

Comment: @CL. what if it sleeps during the transaction?

Comment: If a transaction takes too much time, it is not of the appropriate size. ☺ Anyway, the transactions should be small enough so that you do not lose too much.

Comment: @mbdavis see if this link helps you out. [Java Sleep Detection](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/messagehandling/article.php/c6907/JavaC-PC-Standby-Detect-and-Prevent.htm)

Comment: @CL. I need large transaction sizes for performance - small transactions have proved too slow. Crashing during a transaction seems to corrupt the database.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is so big in size it is better to use BigData like Hadoop, Apache Spark or MySQL server at least because SQLite mostly crashes when you insert to many data.

And another solution is to make your app insertion or whatever you do with database continue from the last stopped point. In this case you could be able to stop or resume anytime you want without worrying about your computer will sleep or not.